# Trouble compiling LiquidFun Paint - "Found SWIG , requires 2.0.11 or above. Stop"

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, paint, swig, liquidfun

I am having trouble compiling [LiquiFun Paint](https://github.com/google/LiquidFunPaint)

I am using Eclipse. I receive

> Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?] java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified

I am using Windows 8.1. I have set the following Environment Variables in Eclipse:

- LIQUIDFUN_SRC_PATH
- NDKROOT
- SWIG_BIN

(there is a value for CYGWIN of nodosfilewarning)

I get the folling error in Eclipse:

> C:\ndk\ndk-build.cmd" all  process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,
>   C:\swigwin-2.0.1 -version, ...) failed.
>   C:\liquidfun-master\liquidfun\Box2D/../Box2D/swig/jni/Android.mk:62:
>   *** Found SWIG , requires 2.0.11 or above.  Stop.

I have installed SWIG 3.0.5 and tried 2.0.1. Both result in the same error above.

In addition to the above error there are compiler errors for

import com.google.fpl.liquidfun.World;

it cannot find that import.

I am using Build Command ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd

I am using r10e (64-bit) NDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Try running your build in a cygwin shell?  Something like:

C:\cygwin\bin\bash /cygdrive/c/ndk/ndk-build.cmd

> CreateProcess(NULL, C:\swigwin-2.0.1 -version, ...)

What is your SWIG_BIN set to?  It looks like it's set to "C:\swigwin-2.0.1" but should probably be set to something like "C:\swigwin-2.0.1\swig.exe"

Comment: The issue was indeed that the SWIG_BIN did not include swig.exe. Thanks.

Comment: My system doesn't this swingwin folder.Is it some thing I need to install manually.If then can I know where I can download it?